# Finding the end of an interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given

$$a(x) = n(6x-1)^n$$

I have calculated the ratio: $a(n+1)/a(n)$, and have found that as $n$ approaches infinity, the limit approaches $6x-1$.

I am asked to find the left hand end of this interval of convergence.

I calculated $6x-1 < 1$ (as the ratio must be less than one for convergence),
to which i got $x<1/3$.

From this, I think that the range of interest would be from $-1/3$, to $1/3$, and I will need to check these endpoints for convergence too. But, the answer to this question is $0$. How can I "test" this range to find that the left-most end of the interval of convergence is $0$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please use MathJax.

Comment: You might look at $6x-1 \gt -1$ too, i.e. saying you have convergence iff  $|6x-1| \lt 1$

Answer (score 0):

Your way is right, the ratio test (or the root test) leads to the condition

$$|6x-1|<1 \iff -1<6x-1<1 \iff 0<x<\frac13$$

and we have

- $a(0) = n(6x-1)^n=(-1)^nn$
- $a(1/3) = n(6x-1)^n=n$